# How to copy a tensor with gradient information into another tensor?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

I have a tensor `A` of shape `(1, 768)` with gradient and a tensor `B` of shape `(2, 4, 768)`. I want to replace some values of tensor `B` with tensor `A` and have it pass back the gradient normally. However, direct assignment like `B[batch][replace_ids].data = A` seems to lose all gradients in A while `B[batch][replace_ids] = A` will get a `RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.` Is there any feasible way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Would be great if we can see a MWE but I guess you can try

```py
B = B.clone()[batch, replace_ids] = A
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It seems to train fine now!